# Can you debug on a WP7 device when developing in a VM?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-phone-7, virtualbox

I'm planning to develop for Windows Phone 7 inside a VirtualBox VM on an OSX host.  Am I going to be able to debug my app on the device?  I've had problems with USB on VMs before.

Comment: no XP, no Atom proc, no virtual

Comment: I just tried installing the windows phone dev package and it told me XP wasn't supported, how about with Vista or Windows 7?

Comment: You need to do a bit of hacking to get past the XP check. The situation should be the same for Win7.. I wouldn't bother with Vista personally as there's been a number of reported issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting the system requirements of the emulator ...

[Setup and System Requirements for Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626524%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

... these constraints won't be in the way if you're not intending to use it.

Joel blogged his experiences doing just this with XP here.

[Running the Windows Phone Dev Tools on Windows XP](http://www.j2i.net/BlogEngine/post/2010/08/17/Running-the-Windows-Phone-Dev-Tools-on-Windows-XP.aspx)

Provided your VM environment can handle the USB connection and I don't see any barriers to this.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone development isn't support on XP at all (VM or otherwise), so I think that's going to be the first roadblock.